# Копирование строк в SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Добрый день! Помогите плз. разобраться. Нужно сделать копирование товаров в пределах одной таблицы sql. Например есть таблица товаров интерне-магазина и есть похожие товары которые лень вносить каждый раз заново, а было бы удобно нажать на похожем товаре "Копировать", подправить нужные данные и добавить как новый товар.

Хотел сделать на основе функции удаления, заменив $action на $action_copy а "delete" на "copy", но не получилось

```html
$action = $_GET["action"];
if (isset($action))
{
   $id = (int)$_GET["id"]; 
   switch ($action) {

     case 'delete':
   if ($_SESSION['delete_tovar'] == '1')
   {
           $delete = mysql_query("DELETE FROM category WHERE id = '$id'",$link);      
   }else
   {
      $msgerror = 'У вас нет прав на удаление товаров!';
   }
     break;        
 } 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO category SELECT * FROM category WHERE id = '$id'",$link);
```

Но! Если поле ID - первичный ключ или на нем уникальный индекс, то нужно исключить поле ID из вставки. Для этого придется перечислить все поля таблицы кроме ID. Т.е.

```
INSERT INTO category (<список полей кроме ID>) SELECT <список полей кроме ID> FROM category WHERE id =
```

Другой вариант сделать то же - селектом извлечь запись и отдельным инсертом её вставить.

Comment: Спасибо! Действительно все работает!!!!!!!!!!! Вы очень помогли!

Comment: @billov Отметьте ответ как верный, если он вам действительно помог